# Plotting "before and after" graphs in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have used gnuplot succesfully to plot boxplots. But now I would like to stick to gnuplot for all my plotting needs and looking to do something that eg. Prism can do:

http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/132/

I only have two columns of data (before and after) and want all pairs to be joined up with a line. If anyone has any idea, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible out of the box, so it requires some fiddling.

- The xtics are set manually, `0` is the `x`-value of 'Before', `1` for 'After'. These numerical values must be used explicitely later in the plots.
- The lines are plotted as `arrows` without heads. Using `lc variable` (i.e. `linecolor variable`), we can use the last column of the `using` statement to select the color from the respective line type.
- The 'Before' points are plotted first. Unfortunately, there is no option `pointtype variable`, so I use the `plot for` iteration to assign each point a different `pointtype` (`pt`).
- I use the `stats` command to determine the number of points to plot. To get the total count, I must sum up the `records`, which are the inside points, and the `outofrange` points, because the classification is done based on the first column's value, which conflict with the 'manual' xtics settings for the 'Before' and 'After' labels.

These are the main points. Of course, there are many other possibilities (using line styles etc.), but should be a good starting point.

The script is:

```
reset
file='beforeafter.txt'

set xtics ('Before' 0, 'After' 1)
set xrange [-0.2:1.2]
set offset 0,0,0.2,0.2

stats file nooutput
cnt = int(STATS_records+STATS_outofrange)

plot for [i=0:cnt-1] file using (0):1 every ::i::i with points lc i+1 pt (6+i) ps 2 t '',\
     for [i=0:cnt-1] file using (1):2 every ::i::i with points lc i+1 pt (6+i) ps 2 t '',\
     file using (0):1:(1):($2-$1):($0+1) with vectors nohead lc variable t ''
```

With the test data `beforeafter.txt`:

```
1  5.5
2  0.3
3  3
```

And you get the result:

[image]

### Using line styles

Another variant uses line styles to set the color, line type, and point type. For the iterations you must use explicitely `ls (i+1)`, whereas for the `vectors` the `as variable` (`arrowstyle variable`) is used. With the `lc variable` it is not possible to set different dash patterns for the arrows.

So here is a, in my opinion, much more readable and flexible variant:

```
reset
set termoption dashed
file='beforeafter.txt'

set xtics ('Before' 0, 'After' 1)
set xrange [-0.2:1.2]
set offset 0,0,0.2,0.2

stats file nooutput
cnt = int(STATS_records+STATS_outofrange)

set style line 1 lt 1 pt 5 ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb '#AE1100'
set style line 2 lt 2 pt 7 ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb '#6EB043'
set style line 3 lt 3 pt 9 ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb '#7777ff'

set for [i=1:3] style arrow i ls i nohead

unset key
plot file using (0):1:(1):($2-$1):($0+1) with vectors as variable,\
     for [i=0:cnt-1] file using (0):1 every ::i::i with points ls (i+1),\
     for [i=0:cnt-1] file using (1):2 every ::i::i with points ls (i+1)
```

With the result:

[image]

Comment: Haven't tried out your code yet, but it looks awesome. Will definitely be coming back to accept it as an answer, just want to try it out first. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: @ilakast The line styles in the example weren't necessary (remainder of some tests). But I added a second script, which is more flexible regarding point and line settings.

Comment: Your scripts are great and I am learning a great deal out of them. I should be more explicit in my question: I have 30 data points per condition (before-after), so I was not looking in having different shapes and colors of lines or points. I can manipulate the size of the points with "pointsize", but I am still trying to make all points and lines black...

Comment: @ilakast Alright, just wanted to show the possibilities. In case you need different pointsizes, maybe even dependent on the actual data change, you can use `pointsize variable`.